# Why this cookie changes value after browser reopening?

Tags: php, session, cookies

Here is a simple php code that starts session and regenerates session id and set cookie lifetime on POST request.

```
<?php
// url: http://localhost/sessiontest/
session_start();
if (isset($_POST['test'])) {
    ini_set('session.cookie_lifetime', 86400);
    session_regenerate_id(true);

    header('Location: http://localhost/sessiontest/');
    return;
}
print_r($_COOKIE);
?>
<html>
    <form method="post" action="">
        <input type="text" name="test" />
        <input type="submit" />
    </form>
</html>
```

I have a problem in firefox 35.0.1. Session id stores in PHPSESSID cookie. After session id regenerates, I close the browser and open it. The cookie value is changed after the browser closing. There is no such problem in chrome.

If you open this page you will see PHPSESSID cookie with some value (value#1)
If you click submit button PHPSESSID cookie will be changed (value#2)

Then if you close firefox 35.0.1 and reopen it you will see that PHPSESSID cookie has value#1. Why does it happen? Is it a bug of firefox?
If you do the same in chrome after reopening you will see value#2

It is very important for me because in my website I do the same when users authenticate. And after browser reopens users are logged out.

Answer (score 0):

When the browser page is reloaded it also resubmits the data in the `$_POST`, `$_REQUEST` and `$_GET` arrays. Firefox may repeat this process whereas Chrome may note that the process has happened once and not resubmit the data.

Firefox will often come up with a "are you sure you wish to resubmit this data" display when you refresh a form populated page, it's just different browsers different data. To ensure the form submission only happens once there are two routes (maybe more):

1) Form and session workings happen on a server page which does not output to the browser instead forwarding to a "completed" browser page. Then refreshing simply reloads the completed page

2) Adding some form of flag, database or (other) cookie controlled that checks if the `$_POST` data has already been submitted using a flag system in the cookie.